# How to activate specific window when certain amount of time passes without any activity only in that specific window?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

Friends I want that when a specific window is idle for 10 minutes then it should first activate that window and then send f4 key. I work on some online software and it logs out when that software is idle or inactive for 10 minutes and to log in again is very cumbersome and hectic work, so I want when 10 minutes pass without any activity (only on that window) then that window should be activated and f4 key should be sent automatically.

That windows title as shown in window spy is this-

Finacle - Microsoft Internet Explorer

ahk_class IEFrame

ahk_exe IEXPLORE.EXE

Comment: Is the web page in a browser with multiple tabs open or is it in its own window all by itself?  The latter is an easier problem to solve.  And by 'idle', would it be accurate to define 'idle' by saying that the window is not active?  In other words, can you define idle time as the time that the window has been in the background? i.e., not been active?

Comment: Dear @JJohnston2 the webpage opens in its own window. It has no multi tab window. Here idle means unless keystroke like f4 or f10 are made in that window, that window will remain idle. in other words once f4 or f10 is pressed in that window then it will become active once again. So i want that it should automatically send f4 or f10 keystroke in that window when 10 minutes pass to the previous f4 or f10 in that window. Is this possible. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this... I am unable to test it.  There are lots of things that could cause it to possibly not work so you may need to experiment a bit.

First start the script (it will stay running), then activate the IE window using F4 or F10, afterwhich you should see the tooltip pop up and it should re-activate every 10 minutes from the last time it was manually activated.

```
#NoEnv
#Persistent

winFinacle := "Finacle - Microsoft Internet Explorer ahk_exe IEXPLORE.EXE"

return


#IfWinActive, %winFinacle%
~F4::           ; tilde allows pass-through of the keystroke to the program
~F10::
KeepFinacleActive:

    ToolTip Activating Finacle...
    sleep 1000
    tooltip

    ; Enable timer to call itself after desired time once user kicks things off with initial key press
    SetTimer, KeepFinacleActive, 600000      ; 10min * 60sec/min * 1000ms/sec = 600000

    BlockInput, On                  ; block user input in case this happens in the middle of other user activity
    WinActivate, %winFinacle%
    WinWaitActive,,,2               ; wait a max of 2 seconds for it to be active
    if not ErrorLevel               ; if there was no error...
    {
        sleep 200                   ; give IE some nominal time to load (adjust as needed)
        SendInput {F10}             ; send a keystroke (this will be a duplicate keystroke first time user executes manually)
    }
    else  ; else if we couldn't find the window...
    {
        tooltip Couldn't find window during attempted activation...
        sleep 2000
        tooltip
    }
    BlockInput, Off

return

#IfWinActive    ; disable for following commands (if any)
```

Comment: Thanks dear @JJohnston2,               thanks a lot for your kind help..